# git compile error make[1]: execvp: /usr: Permission denied

Tags: git, makefile, debian

all

I try to install git with source codes.

I ran the `./configure` script and it succeeded.

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/git --with-openssl --with-libpcre=/usr/local/git --with-curl=/usr --with-expat=/usr/local/git --with-iconv=/usr/local/git --with-zlib=/usr/local/git --with-perl=/usr --with-python=/usr --with-tcltk=no --with-pager=/usr/bin/pager --with-editor=/usr/bin/vim --with-gitconfig=/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig --with-gitattributes=/usr/local/git/etc/gitattributes
```

But I got an error when I ran make:

```
............
SUBDIR perl
/usr Makefile.PL PREFIX='/usr/local/git' INSTALL_BASE='' --localedir='/usr/local/git/share/locale'
make[1]: execvp: /usr: Permission denied
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'perl.mak' failed
make[1]: *** [perl.mak] Error 127
Makefile:1781: recipe for target 'perl/perl.mak' failed
make: *** [perl/perl.mak] Error 2
```

Who can tell me that what files missed?

Comment: **My configure script is**
`$./configure --prefix=/usr/local/git --with-openssl --with-libpcre=/usr/local/git --with-curl=/usr --with-expat=/usr/local/git --with-iconv=/usr/local/git --with-zlib=/usr/local/git --with-perl=/usr --with-python=/usr --with-tcltk=no --with-pager=/usr/bin/pager --with-editor=/usr/bin/vim --with-gitconfig=/usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig --with-gitattributes=/usr/local/git/etc/gitattributes`

Comment: I'm going to assume that `--with-perl=/usr` is the problem. Why are you passing that? And the same for `--with-python=/usr` and `--with-curl=/usr`? If you want it to use the system defaults you shouldn't need to pass anything there I don't think. Same for `--editor` and `--pager`. Also do you really have your own `expat`, `pcre`, `zlib` and `iconv` in `/usr/local/git`?